# Resource maps Show to /:id instead of /:id/show

Tags: admin-on-rest

Don't know why this is happening, but when click on show button, the server will receive a `GET` request of url `/:id` instead of `/:id/show`. The REST client is `jsonServerRestClient`. I use `Resource` component as the document describes. like:

`<Resource list={MyList} edit={MyEdit} show={MyShow} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the docs of jsonServerRestClient
https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#json-server-rest

You will note that the GET_ONE rest type will generate /:id url to the server only. Show is not a rest type.